# Como funciona o Gerenciamento de Memória, com memória virtual?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-memória, sistema-operacional

Bom estou fazendo a disciplina de Sistemas Operacionais e surgiu uma duvida enquanto leio gerenciamento de memória.

Pelo que eu li, uma forma de abstrair a memória é utilizar registradores base e limite, onde para cada programa na memória física é guardado o seu inicio no registrador base e o final no limite. Até ai OK.
Depois vi formas de gerenciar a memória livre, que é o que fazer quando tirar ou alocar um programa na memória física, dai tem o mapa de bits ou por lista encadeada,no caso da lista encadeada tem os algoritmos first-fit, next-fit, best-fit, worst-fit. Até aí OK.

Então eu entendi até agora que é preciso uma abstração da memória para muitos programas poderem usar e de uma forma de gerenciar o espaço de disponível, como alocar e etc.

Agora estou vendo memória virtual, que pelo que entendi é pra quando o programa não cabe inteiro na memória física e você precisa executa-lo mesmo que ele não esteja inteiro na memória. Então usa o esquema de paginação e tabela de paginas, que quando vc precisar buscar alguma instrução na memória a MMU(*Memory Management Unity*) faz o calculo do endereço absoluto através da do quadro de pagina que essa pagina referencia e seu deslocamento.

Agora que entra minha duvida, quando se usa paginação não usa o esquema de registrador base e limite? Pq uma vez que todo processo vai estar guardado nas paginas e a MMU faz o cálculo pro endereço absoluto não precisa mais de registrador base e limite.